# Prove that $x_1^4+x_2^4\geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, quadratics

If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the solutions of the equation $x^2+px- \frac{a}{p^2}=0$, a=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+2$ and $p \in R-\{0\}$
Then prove that $x_1^4+x_2^4\geq 2$.

Can i go with Viet’s Formulas $x_1+x_2=-b/a$, then apply the power of 4 on both sides but I’m stuck here. Someone help please.

Comment: What has this to do with [tag:complex-analysis] or [tag:linear-algebra]?

Comment: It’s from Analysis With Algebra class so why.

Comment: It is algebra, but lot linear algebra, and it has nothing to do with analysis.

Comment: @BlinerëBytyci Is that a reason for you to use the [tag:complex-analysis] tag?

Comment: As an idea (I haven't thought this through to carefully but I assume it will work out) and is purely algebraic. If you have a quadratic $X^2 + bX +c$ then you know its roots $\alpha,\beta$ satisfy $\alpha+\beta = -b$ and $\alpha\beta = c$. Notice that $\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2} = (\alpha+\beta)^{2} - 2\alpha\beta = b^{2}-2c$. Similarly, you can express $\alpha^{4}+\beta^{4}$ in terms of the coefficients, then you should be able to derive the inequality... (hopefully).

Comment: Thank you so much. ☺️

Comment: By 1/sqrt(2)+2 do you mean $1\over\sqrt2+2$ or ${1\over\sqrt2}+2$? (Also, by "p e R\o" are you saying that $p$ is a nonzero real number?)

Comment: The first one for a, and yes nonzero real number.

Comment: Isn’t edited correct a=1/(sqrt(2)+2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align} x_1^4 + x_2^4 &= (x_1+x_2)^4 - 4x_1^3x_2-6x_1^2x_2^2-4x_1x_2^2 = \\ 
&= (x_1+x_2)^4 - x_1x_2 (4x_1^2+6x_1x_2+4x_2^2) = \\ 
&= (x_1+x_2)^4 - x_1x_2 \big(4(x_1+x_2)^2-2x_1x_2\big)
\end{align}
Then use the Vieta's formulae for $x_1+x_2$ and $x_1x_2$. See if you can show that what you get is greater of equal to $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much !